# Why is eventListener not being added?

Tags: javascript, html

I have code here in a todo list that can add and delete tasks. I'm trying to implement code to edit tasks after they are added by double clicking. Right now the code should just log to the console after double clicking the LI element but it's not doing anything.

```
newTodoInput.addEventListener('keyup', function addTodoController(event){
    if ( event.keyCode === 13){
        if ( newTodoInput.value !== '' ){
            var newTask = todos.addTaskToList(newTodoInput.value.trim(), todos.taskList);
            var clone = templateContent.cloneNode(true);
            clone.querySelector("label").appendChild(document.createTextNode(newTodoInput.value.trim()));
            todoList.appendChild(clone);
            newTodoInput.value = '';
            deletingTasks();
            editingTasks();
        }
    }
}); // END addEventListener(addTodoController)
function deletingTasks() {
    var deleteTaskButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button.destroy');
    _.last(deleteTaskButtons).addEventListener('click', function removeLi(){
        //console.log(event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
        event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(event.target.parentNode.parentNode);
        todos.deleteTask(_.indexOf(deleteTaskButtons, event.target), todos.taskList);
    });
}

function editingTasks(){
    var editTask = document.querySelectorAll('li');
    _.last(editTask).addEventListener('dblclick', function taskEdit(){
        console.log("Edit this task!");
    });
}
```

I'm invoking the editingTasks function every time a task is added just like I did with the deleting tasks function so that the event listeners will be added to each li element as it's added but I'm not getting anything. Any pointers to why this code doesn't work? Here's the HTML if needed:

```
<ul class="todo-list">
                <!-- These are here just to show the structure of the list items -->
                <!-- List items should get the class `editing` when editing and `completed` when marked as completed -->
                <template id='newtasktemplate'>
                    <li>
                        <div class="view">
                            <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">
                            <label class="tasking"></label>
                            <button class="destroy"></button>
                        </div>
                        <input class="edit" value="Rule the web">
                    </li>
                </template>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the last `<li>` is the one you just added?

Comment: I'm fairly certain, there's definitely a chance that I'm wrong (newbie). I figured it'd work the same way as the destroy buttons did with the deletingTasks function.

Comment: Well, you're using a much more specific selector for the deletingTasks that won't possibly pick something other than the last delete button.  But, any other `<li>` tag in your page that happens to be after the ones you're adding (like maybe even one in the template) could ruin your code.  How about a more specific selector that you're sure targets only the right `<li>` tags?

Comment: That's a good point, any tips on how to do that? Links that might help? I'm iffy on referring to html elements.

Comment: Just like your delete buttons have a unique class name on them, do the same with your `<li>` tags that you want to target.

Comment: And there it goes! I added a class in the template list so that when the code went active it would add an li with that class. Invoking editTask to look for that class made every one of them have the event listener. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Since what we talked about in comments seems to have worked, I added that to an answer so you can accept that answer to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely that your code that does:

```
var editTask = document.querySelectorAll('li');
_.last(deleteTaskButtons).addEventListener(...)
```

may not be selecting the right `<li>` tag.  My suggestion is to change your template to add a unique class name to the `<li>` tag as in:

```
<li class="myListItem">
```

And, then change your code to this:

```
var editTask = document.querySelectorAll('.myListItem');
_.last(deleteTaskButtons).addEventListener(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping you would post an answer so I could accept it!